# Wrong user when pushing to Github from VSCode

Tags: windows, git, github, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode and Github and I use Windows 10. I have 2 Github accounts, one "Private" and one "Work". I started out with "Private" but I am not using it anymore. I linked the VSCode account to "Work" and verified it has done this correctly.

Now, when I push a file from local to remote, it keeps pushing it with "Private". So I checked how to solve this and changed 2 things:

1. In Git bash, I typed: `git config --global user.name` and `git config user.name`, and found out it said "Private" for both. So I entered: `git config --global user.name "Work"` and `git config user.name "Work"`, which changed this to "Work" for both
2. On my laptop, I went to Start -> Control Panel -> User accounts -> Manage Your Credentials -> Windows Credentials and removed the credentials for "Private"

I hoped these 2 actions would solve the issue, but unfortunately it doesn't. Is there anywhere else where I should change something?

Comment: Windows user accounts are unrelated to GitHub user accounts. Why do you expect changing the former to have any effect on the latter?

Comment: Check out this link it may help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605623/10705348

Comment: @IInspectable, that's not true it's using Windows Credentials for HTTPS Urls, see also comments in link provided by Abdul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue with help from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605623/10705348) provided by @Abdul:
I typed `git config --list`, which showed an overview of the credentials cashed. There I noticed `user.email` was still using the email address of my "Private" account. So I typed `git config --global user.email <my "work" email address>` and that solved the issue - when I push now to remote it's done via my "Work" git account

Answer (score 0):

The `user.name` and `user.email` have nothing to do with *authentication*, only commit authorship.

And Windows Credential Manager is only used for HTTPS URLs.

If your remote repository is referenced with an SSH URL, said credential manager would not be involved at all.

Comment: I use HTTPS URLs, so that's why it keeps using "Private"